# Can we map duplicate beans(of same name in different packages) in hibernate hql

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables **tbl_aaaa_entity** and **tbl_bbbb_entity** .

And I created two beans **com.xxx.aaaa.Entity** and **com.xxx.bbbb.Entity** .

If I use HQL as

> "From Entity"

it retrieves from **com.xxx.aaaa.Entity** by default and not from **com.xxx.bbbb.Entity** .

Any how I resolved by renaming two bean classes. But Is it possible to have like that working?

Comment: can you try `from com.xxx.aaa.Entity`

Comment: It worked., Thank you @Prasanna Kumar

Comment: That's k..i ll post the answer accept it..it will be useful for other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **include** the package name with the mapping class name.

like..

```
from package.mappingClass
```

it avoids the conflict between same named classes.